# ARM template outputs

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I see many templates online using primaryEndpoints ouput parameter in ARM templates, but I am not sure how they actually found it as it's not mentioned in the docs. What is the best way to find out the available outputs for a resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one of the way is to output the whole object with all properties and values.

```
    "outputs": {
    "myObject": {
        "type": "Object",
        "value": "[reference(parameters('myResources'))]"
    }
```

you can also use [resource explorer](https://resources.azure.com) to browse resources that are provissioned